# Inkscape - Scanned Text To Vector Image

Tags: inkscape, image-trace, bitmap

[image]

Im trying to make a clipping mask from the text in the included image, Ive tried tracing to bitmap but cant get the threshold quite right. Is there something Im missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there isn't enough contrast in the image to get a good result.

If you open the image in GIMP, invert it, and do a levels adjustment to adjust the contrast, crop it, then copy and paste that into Inkscape, you can get a decent result.

For example

[image]

Comment: Ahhh yes, brilliant then I just trace to bitmap from there, thanks alot.